# C#: How to make array in class accessible from other classes?

Tags: c#

I am learning C# and I am trying to put color schemes/themes into Multidimentional Array so I can access them from any other class.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace sFirstApp
{
    public class colorSchemes
    {
        string[,] colorBase = new string[3, 4];
        colorBase[0, 0] = "D60000";     //Main Background.
        colorBase[0, 1] = "DB3E25";     //Text Color.
        colorBase[0, 2] = "FF5940";     //Text Shadow.
    }
}
```

Visual Studio keeps saying:
The name 'colorBase' does not exist in the current context.

Where is my problem and how is this kind of class called?

Also the reason I am trying to use 2D array is because I want 1st dimension of array to specify Theme #.

I am planning to store Theme # in App Settings as number, then simply use 2D arrays like:

ColorTheme[theme #][theme element]

Comment: This is a perfectly fine beginner question IMHO. It contains a short piece of code illustrating the problem (though the `using` and `namespace` parts could be omitted) and a clear problem statement.

Comment: You should expose a method in this class to get access to the internal data. And call your class by the correct casing: ColorSchemes.

Comment: Why are those values being assigned in plain class declaration and not inside a constructor or method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use array indexes to arbitrarily mean something more than a position.
Use named properties for each of these colors, and even better, use [`System.Drawing.Color`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx).

This would be a good style for maintanable, modern C#:

```
namespace FirstApp
{
    public static class ColorSchemes
    {
        public struct ThemeColors
        {
            public Color MainBackground { get; internal set;  }
            public Color TextColor { get; internal set; }
            public Color TextShadow { get; internal set;  }
        }

        private static readonly ThemeColors[] Colors =
        {
            new ThemeColors
            {
                MainBackground = Color.FromArgb(0xD6, 0x00, 0x00),
                TextColor = Color.FromArgb(0xDB, 0x3E, 0x25),
                TextShadow = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x59, 0x40)
            }
        };

        public static ThemeColors GetThemeColors(int themeIndex)
        {
            if (themeIndex < 0 || themeIndex >= Colors.Length)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            return Colors[themeIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

The colors can now be accessed with a simple, readable `ColorSchemes.GetThemeColors(0).TextColor`. They can also be loaded from other locations dynamically without breaking an API by using [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx). Additional themes can be added simply.

For proper object oriented design, there should probably be a `Theme` class that returns a `ThemeColors` struct when requested for its colors instead of using a static `ColorSchemes` class.

That could be implemented something like this (keep in mind explicit constructors should probably be used for much of this):

```
namespace FirstApp
{
    public class Theme
    {
        public struct ThemeColors
        {
            public Color MainBackground { get; internal set; }
            public Color TextColor { get; internal set; }
            public Color TextShadow { get; internal set; }
        }

        // Example other property
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ThemeColors Colors { get; set; }
    }

    public static class DefaultThemes
    {
        public static Theme MainTheme =>
            new Theme
            {
                Name = "Main Theme",
                Colors = new ThemeColors
                {
                    MainBackground = Color.FromArgb(0xD6, 0x00, 0x00),
                    TextColor = Color.FromArgb(0xDB, 0x3E, 0x25),
                    TextShadow = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x59, 0x40)
                }
            };
    }
}
```

Then, you'd have `DefaultThemes.MainTheme.Colors.TextShadow`.

Comment: The reason I wanted to store colors in 2 Dimensional Arrays is so I could store SelectedTheme # in App Settings and then simply load it everywhere as: ColorScheme[theme#][theme Element]

Comment: @AleRemote225 In this case, the theme could very well be a number. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @AleRemote225 Sorry, I should have said "edit my answer".

Answer (score 2):

You can create a public method in the class of the array.

```
public string GetColorBase(int position1, int position2){
    return colorBase[position1, position2];
}
```

Then use the method, for example

```
colorSchemes oColorSchemes = new colorSchemes();
string ColorBase = oColorSchemes.GetColorBase(0, 1);
```

Thanks @JeremyKato for correction

Comment: You probably should change the parameters to take two `int`s - it's easily possible that he could add items to the other dimensions of the array.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by marking the array `public`

```
public string[,] colorBase = new string[3, 4];
colorBase[0, 0] = "D60000";     //Main Background.
colorBase[0, 1] = "DB3E25";     //Text Color.
colorBase[0, 2] = "FF5940";     //Text Shadow.
```

To use the class from another namespace you need add the following using statement on top. More about Access Modifiers can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

```
using sFirstApp;
```

From another place inside the app you can then say:

```
var theme = new colorSchemes();
var colors = theme.colorBase;
```

Comment: He also needs an instance

Comment: Not really a good idea to be exposing the array publicly. He should access this via a well defined method.

Comment: @ManoDestra, you are absolutely right. the code above was just to demonstrate how to mark a property public.

Comment: @FlorianSchaal To be completely accurate, this is a *field*, not a property. Properties use getters and setters, while fields are like variables for an object.

Comment: @Kupiakos you are correct. I have edited the answer.